# Can't get index.php to work on LAMP on LINODE

Tags: php, facebook, lamp, linode

sorry if this question is very basic , but I am trying to run the example facebook application facebook gives you.
I am using linode, and installed the stock linode LAMP stackscript. I installed PHP and I then downloaded the code from facebook to a facebook folder in the default site folder, /srv/www//public_html/facebook.
I try and go to the site page in the browser with no success.
Im sure im missing something basic so sorry in advance

Comment: Start with making sure PHP works. Does it? If not troubleshoot properly setting up PHP and Apache. We can't help you without knowing that. Then, anything in the error log? Any other info specific to your setup?

Comment: is there a simple test to check if php is working?

Comment: `<?php echo 'hello world'; ?>` works for you?

Comment: yes it does, i also checked by creating a file <? 
phpinfo(); 
?> and it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that your Apache configuration doesn't have `index.php` set as a valid `DirectoryIndex`.

Search your configure files (usually in a `dir.conf` file (sometimes in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/)) for a the `DirectoryIndex` directive, and verify that it has `index.php` in it.  Also, these definitions are in order of precedence.  So if `index.html` is first, and `index.php` is last, if your folder has an `index.html` file in it, your `index.php` will never be loaded.  So, either remove the `index.html` from your document root, or move `index.php` in the `DirectoryIndex` directive to the left.

Also, make sure you have `display_errors` set to `on` in your `php.ini` and `error_reporting` set to `E_ALL`.  This will tell you when you have parse errors and other fatal errors in your php code, so you won't have to go guessing.

Comment: hi,just checked index.php is in there, and i moved it to the front of the list, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: i just tinkered a bit more, it only doesn't work when i have fbml stuff in the file, otherwise it loads fine.

Comment: im an idiot, facebook started blocking fbml in march sorry guys

Comment: nope sorry have to take that back. Tried using a sample iframe index.php file from facebook and still fail :(

Comment: Could there be a PHP error on the index file?  Check your Apache error log to see if there's anything there

Comment: that was it errors in the php file, sorry for all the confusion, reminds me that its always the simplest reason

Comment: I added a bit to make sure you turn on error reporting, so you can catch those problems in the future.

Comment: thanks, just a heads up for others the problem stemmed from the fact that i did not have php-curl installed on my server which was required by the example facebook code, i found this out from the php error logs.